# Create DB Record From API Call Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, api, put

I searched around but couldn't find something that matched the situation I'm in although I did find some great information.

Context - I'm a FE dev who is EXTREMELY new to C#/Entity/API creation and I'm stumbling my way through as I learn so forgive my ignorance.

We have an API written in Entity and I'm trying to create a SQL database record based on information that will eventually be submitted by a user through an Angular front end.

The controller will (if possible) have a GET and the DB call (haven't figured out if this will be the same as a PUT but I think so?)
Here is my controller code thus far:

```
    using System;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure;
    using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Net;
    using System.Net.Http;
    using System.Web.Http;
    using System.Web.Http.Description;
    using SageApi.Models;
    using SageApi.SageBOI;
    using SageDataAccess;
    
    namespace SageApi.Controllers
    {
        /*This was commented out as I'm not sure how to test it without a PUT method 
public class updScoutToTextBuilderInfoDB : DbContext
        {
            public updScoutToTextBuilderInfoDB(updScoutToTextBuilderInfoDTO data)
            {
                using (MAS_PLUEntities entities = new MAS_PLUEntities())
                {
                    var newRecord = new APP_Customer_Testing()
                    {
                        id = data.id,
                        FirstName = data.superFirstName,
                        LastName = data.superLastName,
                        Email1 = data.superEmail1,
                        Email2 = data.superEmail2,
                        Email3 = data.superEmail3,
                        CompanyName = data.company,
                        SalesOrderNum = data.salesorderno,
                        PhoneNum = data.superPhone,
                        Subdivision = data.subdivision
                    };
    
                    entities.APP_Customer_Testing.Add(newRecord);
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }*/
    
        public class updScoutToTextBuilderInfoController : ApiController
        {
            public IEnumerable<APP_Customer_Testing> Get()
            {
                using (MAS_PLUEntities entities = new MAS_PLUEntities())
                {
                    return entities.APP_Customer_Testing.ToList();
                }
            }

            [HttpPut]
            public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] updScoutToTextBuilderInfoDTO data)
            {
    
                try
                {
                    {
                        if (entities.APP_Customer_Testing.FirstOrDefault() != null)
                        {
                            var newRecord = new APP_Customer_Testing()
                            {
                                id = data.id,
                                FirstName = data.superFirstName,
                                LastName = data.superLastName,
                                Email1 = data.superEmail1,
                                Email2 = data.superEmail2,
                                Email3 = data.superEmail3,
                                CompanyName = data.company,
                                SalesOrderNum = data.salesorderno,
                                PhoneNum = data.superPhone,
                                Subdivision = data.subdivision
                            };
    
                            entities.APP_Customer_Testing.Add(newRecord);
                            entities.SaveChanges();

                            var message = "Entities are not null";
                            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, message);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            var message = "ELSE statement - entities came back NULL";
                            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message);
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var errorMsg = "Error Message: " + ex;
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorMsg);
                }
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Customer updated successfully!");
               
            }
        }
    }
```

When I hit my endpoint through Postman, I get the response (paraphrasing):

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Line 72

Line 72 in my code is `var newRecord = new APP_Customer_Testing()`.

This is where I get lost though.  I'm not looking for anyone to give me the solution I just need some help with pointing me in the right direction.

If you need more information please let me know and I'll be happy to provide whatever I can.

Thank you for any and all help you may be able to provide.

*UPDATE*
Here is the code I updated:

```
[HttpPut]
    public HttpResponseMessage Put([FromBody] updScoutToTextBuilderInfoDTO data)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MAS_PLUEntities entities = new MAS_PLUEntities())
            {
                if (data == null)
                {
                    var newRecord = new updScoutToTextBuilderInfoDTO()
                    {
                        id = data.id,
                        superFirstName = data.superFirstName,
                        superLastName = data.superLastName,
                        superEmail1 = data.superEmail1,
                        superEmail2 = data.superEmail2,
                        superEmail3 = data.superEmail3,
                        company = data.company,
                        salesorderno = data.salesorderno,
                        superPhone = data.superPhone,
                        subdivision = data.subdivision

                    };
                    entities.APP_Customer_Testing.Add(newRecord);
                    entities.SaveChanges();
                    
                    var message = "Record created successfully";
                    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, message);
                }
                else
                {
                    var message = "Record not created";
                    return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, message);
                    throw new ArgumentNullException("data");
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var errorMsg = "Error Message: " + ex;
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, errorMsg);
        }
}
```

But I'm getting an error related to this line:
`entities.APP_Customer_Testing.Add(newRecord)` that says `Argument 1: Cannot convert from SageApi.Models.updScoutToTextBuilderInfoDTO to SageDataAccess.APP_Customer_Testing`

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio

Comment: The code following line 72 is initializing the new instance so I believe an error in initialization will be reported against the first line. The NullReferenceException is likely due to 'data' being null. This is commonly when WCF/ASP.Net cannot deserialize the passed in data from the client to the desired type. It's advisable to always assert your function parameters to avoid arbitrary null ref exceptions. I.e. first line of the function: `if (data == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("data")`. This guards all future reference to data (provided it isn't mutated) and gives you a useful err.

Comment: HI @StevePy thank you for your response.  I added the line of code along with an HTTP message and it turns out my data variable is coming in as `NULL`.  

I'm confused because I thought I was passing values in from the `updScoutToTextBuilderInfoDTO` file as the parameters of `data`.

I'm confused on how I would get data into my PUT request from the user if not through the DTO variable being passed in.

Comment: I updated with an error I received after adding the Null check :)

Comment: I think `var newRecord = new updScoutToTextBuilderInfoDTO()` should be `var newRecord = new APP_Customer_Testing()`. The new record you want to add to the DbContext would need to be the Entity, not the DTO. When working with Entities and DTOs/ViewModels you need to map them between each other. If the properties are named the same, a library like Automapper can help do this by convention or configuration if you need to rename/reorganize for a DTO.

Comment: Thank you again @StevePy - I was able to get it to post to the DB by manually setting the values in `var recordToAdd = new APP_Customer_Testing()` but I'm still confused on how i would get a record to create via a PUT request.

I'm unsure on how to get the body from the HTTP request.  Any ideas?